# onclick call with params

Tags: javascript

I've got a function, like this:

```
menu[0].onclick = function() {
    filters.reset_all();
    clients.get();
}
```

So it's called when user clicks on the first menu element. Now I need to call it form the other place and what I've done is this:

```
    if (li.onclick) { //li and menu[0] above are the same
        li.onclick.call();
    }
```

and it works well.

But now I need to pass some params to `onclick` function. I've tried this `.call(some_param);` but `arguments` array in `onclick` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:** changed into this:

```
menu[0].onclick = function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    filters.reset_all();
    clients.get();
}
```

and

```
li.onclick.call(li,param);
```

still nothing

Comment: why not call `li.onclick()` directly?

Comment: changed to `li.onclick(param)`, but still can't access it

Comment: that is because the original signature accepts no arguments (`function()`). see [**jfriend00**'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12259656/547020) for a more semantic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
call(object, param1, param2, param3...);
```

In your case you can write

```
li.onclick.call(li, param1);
```

Comment: What the OP is trying to do makes no sense because when `li.onclick()` is called by a real click will have the event object in place of `param1`, so the code in that function can't use `param1` reliably.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `.call()` is the value for the `this` pointer.  The 2nd, 3rd, etc... arguments get passed to the function.  You only need to use `.call()` if you're explicitly trying to set the `this` pointer.  Otherwise, you can just directly call the function `li.onclick()`.

Event handlers are generally called by the system and when that happens, they are passed the event object as the first argument.  If you want a function available that takes different arguments, you should create your own function for that and not use the event handling function.  Your event handler can also call this other function if desired.

```
menu[0].onclick = function() {
    myFunc("aaa");
}

function myFunc(arg1) {
    // do whatever here
    filters.reset_all();
    clients.get();
}

if (li.onclick) {
    myFunc("bbb");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `call()` is the context (in this case `this`) the rest of the parameters go into the arguments array in order. If you use `apply()` instead of call then you have just two parameters: `apply(this, arguments_array)`